# Example of a simple module which does not occur in the regular module?

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, modules, projective-module, algebras

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ be a $K$-algebra.

I know, if $A$ is artinain algebra, then by *Krull-Schmidt Theorem*  $A$ , as a left regular module, can be written as a direct sum of indecomposable $A$-modules, that is

$A=\oplus_{i=1}^n S_i$ where each $S_i$ is indecomposable $A$-module

Moreover, each $S_i$ contains only one maximal submodule, which is given by $J_i= J(A)S_i$, and every simple $A$-module is isomorphic to some $A/J_i$.

My question is that, can you please tell me an example of a non simisimple algebra, or a ring, such that it has a simple module which does not occur in the regular module.

By occur I mean it has to be isomorphic to a simple submodule of a regular module

Comment: Every simple module is cyclic, so occurs is in the regular module.

Comment: @ Jack Schmidt that is a vague answer for me can you please tell me more? or at least outline of the proof of  your claim. Thank you for replying.

Comment: [This was also posted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/138112/1916). Please note that [crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068) - try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site. If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thank you for warning me, as you can see this is my first post and I did not know the rules. I will try to a void this an other time.

Comment: Dear @JackSchmidt : Aren't you are thinking of quotients? That's certainly true, but it looks like the poster means that simple right modules must occur as right submodules of $R_R$, then there are lots of cases where that doesn't happen... It's a bit confusing because their example appears not to illustrate their request very well...

Comment: @rschwieb: yeah the question changed between my comment and yours. "Occurs" in group theory means as a section, not a submodule.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Oh really! I will have to keep that in mind. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the ring $A$ of matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ 0& c\end{pmatrix}$$ then there are 2 simple $A$-modules, both 1 dimensional, one where the matrix above acts by $a$ and one where it acts by $c$.

Now, in any $A$-representation, a simple submodule is a vector sent to a multiple of itself by every element of $A$.  For the left regular representation, the vectors that have this property are $$\begin{pmatrix} d & e\\ 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$$ and this is the sum of two copies of the same simple, where the left action just multiplies by $a$ and never $c$ (if you look at the right regular representation, you'll get the $c$-representation and not the $a$ instead).  The $c$-representation is a quotient of the regular representation, but not a sub.

Comment: Dear Ben Webster: I'm not sure about others, but I don't know what you mean by "acts by a/c." I like the example, though, and I would like to add comments to help. Briefly, the only simple modules are isomorphic to $A/I$ and $A/J$ where $I=\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\}$ and $J=\{\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&c\end{bmatrix}\}$. The only simple left submodule of $A$ is $K=\{\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\}$. $I$ and $J$ are easily seen to be nonisomorphic as left $A$ modules, and $J$ and $K$ are isomorphic as left $A$ modules. This leaves $I$ as the simple module not inside $A$.

Comment: @rschweib the $k$-endomorphisms of a 1-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to $k$, and so a 1-dimensional module is where each ring element is treated like a scalar. "Acts by $a$" means that scalar is $a$.

Comment: I also managed to bungle my notation while trying to fit into the character limit :/ I meant that $R/I$ and $R/J$ are nonisomorphic, and that $R/J\cong K$, if I didn't bungle the left right arrangement...

Comment: @JackSchmidt Sounds like this is pretty common in representation theory... I'll try to remember the usage. Thanks again.

Comment: And I should acknowledge that for some reason I wasn't recognizing the $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ set as a second left ideal of $A$, but as Ben said, it's isomorphic to $K$. I have a feeling I'm still going to wake up in the morning with more regrets to post :S Too late...

Answer (score 3):

Take any commutative nonfield domain. A quotient by a maximal ideal is a simple module, but nonfield domains obviously do not have minimal right ideals.

---

Rings $R$ for which simple right modules embed in $R_R$ are called *right Kasch rings*. Right Artinian local rings and commutative Artinian rings are examples of right Kasch rings, but as you see above domains are not Kasch on either side. More generally, any ring with right socle zero can't be right Kasch.

You can read a bit about then in Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings*.